# Реализовать возможность отмены совершенных действий в приложении

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Разрабатываю приложение для грузоперевозок, по сути это приложение для работы с БД. Есть таблицы для ввода информации. Так вот необходимо реализовать возможность отменны совершенных действий над объектами БД (CRUD операции) как в word и других аналогичных приложений.

Я использую hibernate с аннотациями, сейчас каждое изменение происходит в рамках отдельной сессии как я понимаю. Пример:

Свойства ячейки в tableView контроллера:

```
 columnDateEnd.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Trip, Date> t) -> {
            Trip trip = t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());
            trip.setDateEnd(t.getNewValue());
            tripService.save(trip);
        });
```

TripService просто вызывает метод save репозитория:

```
@Repository
public interface TripRepository extends JpaRepository<Trip,Long> {
}
```

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Каких действий? Какой вложенности? В рамках одной сессии или нужна вся история?

Comment: Отменть CRUD операции, вложенность отсутствует. В рамках одной сессии работы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отменяйте не действия в БД, а действия в tableView.
Сейчас вы после каждого изменения в таблице выполняете запрос на сохранение в БД, что в большинстве случаев не очень разумно (хотя, конечно, все зависит от конкретной задачи). Подумайте над вариантом сохранения по отдельному событию (нажатию на кнопку на панели и т.п.) и сохраняйте при этом все изменения таблицы единовременно. До момента нажатия на эту кнопку вы сможете отменять изменения в таблице, ведя ее историю изменений.